# Entity Framework Core: how to ignore creating class property column in database but fetch property value by raw SQL query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Context config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Ignore(a => a.SomeData);   // don't want to have this in the database
```

Query

```
var results = _dbContext.Persons
                        .FromSqlRaw("SELECT Name, 'calculated by query' SomeData from Persons")
                        .ToList();
```

Running this, `SomeData` property ends up being NULL.

Is there a way to ignore the column for creating the table, but allow fetching of its data using a raw SQL query?

Yes , I want a value of property generated by query, but not have column in database.
I would like to avoid DTO Class,
or anonymous type.

It works when you use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Ignore(a => a.SomeData);
```

db is created, then you comment abowe and add `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(a => a.SomeData).HasComputedColumnSql();`

but it is no a solution :/

So maybe how to add this future to the EntityFrameworkCore?:)
eg. HasComputedRawSqlProperty() -> dont create dbCollumn.

Comment: What version of EF Core do you have?

Comment: So you want to skip a column on table creation but being able to query it ?

Comment: he wants a calculated column in his result set

Comment: EF Core version is 7.0.4

Comment: Yes , I want a value of property generated by query, but not have column in database. I would like to avoid DTO Class, or anonymous type.

Comment: It works when you use 
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Ignore(a => a.SomeData);
db is created,
then you comment abowe and add
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(a => a.SomeData).HasComputedColumnSql();

but it is no a solution :/

Answer (score 1):

you can use Data Annotations - NotMapped Attribute like this

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [NotMapped] has the same result like  Ignore in fluent api

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework Core, there's no direct way to map a property that is both ignored in the database schema and populated with a raw SQL query. However, you can work around this limitation by using the FromSqlRaw() method to execute a raw SQL query and then manually mapping the results to your Person objects without creating a separate DTO class or using anonymous types.

Here's an example of how you might achieve this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Ignore(a => a.SomeData);   // don't want to have this in the database
    }
}
```

When you want to fetch the data with the raw SQL query, use the FromSqlRaw() method and manually map the results to your Person objects:

```
var results = _dbContext.Persons
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT Name, 'calculated by query' AS SomeDataAlias from Persons")
    .Select(x => new Person { Name = x.Name })
    .ToList();

// Map the SomeData property
foreach (var person in results)
{
    person.SomeData = "calculated by query"; // Replace with the actual value from the raw SQL query
}
```

In this example, I've used the AS SomeDataAlias clause to avoid naming conflicts with the ignored property. You can replace the hardcoded value "calculated by query" with the actual value from your raw SQL query.

Comment: It would be ok, but there are  Inheritance classes.
How to map a set of subclasses? :

Comment: You can use Table-per-Type (TPT) or Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance mapping strategies.In either case, you can still use a raw SQL query and manually map the results to your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following helper method that can take any query string and return a list of rows and columns.
You then have to read each row and create the DTO by assigning the properties to the correct column. This might be a solution to you or anyone else looking to run custom queries on tables not mapped by entities.

```
public static List<object[]> ExecuteQuery(DbContext context, string query)
    {
      // Create a list to store the results
      List<object[]> results = new List<object[]>();
      using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
      {
        connection.Open();

        // Create a command using the DbContext's underlying database connection
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
          // Set the command text and type
          command.CommandText = query;
          command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

          // Open the database connection
          context.Database.OpenConnection();

          // Execute the command and retrieve the results
          using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
            // Create an array to hold a single row of results
            var row = new object[reader.FieldCount];

            // Read each row from the data reader
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              // Retrieve the values for the current row and add a shallow copy to the results list
              reader.GetValues(row);
              results.Add((object[])row.Clone());
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Return the list of results
      return results;
    }
```

Usage:

```
     List<object[]> res = ExecuteQuery(_dbContext, "SELECT Name, 'calculated by 
     query' AS SomeDataAlias from Persons");

      //You can also get the first item if only one is expected...
      foreach (object[] dr in res)
      {
        Person p = new Person();

        //Might have to cast value of dr[0] to correct type if it is int or something...
        p.Name = dr[0];
        p.SomeDataAlias = dr[1];
      }
```

Comment: Then you better use Dapper. This method requires a lot of custom code for each queried entity.